# ¿Cómo poner una coma después del tercer dígito?

Tags: java

No tengo mucha experiencia, estoy empezando con Java. El caso es que quiero poner una coma para separarlos al tercer, sexto y noveno dígito.

p.e. dado el siguiente número:
1265377
Quisiera que apareciera algo así: 1,265,377

Espero que me puedan ayudar. No tengo mucha experiencia, recién comienzo. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importa esto

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Declara esto

```
DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
```

Tienes que usar el método "`format`" y pasarle como parámetro una cantidad, te lo devolverá formateado.

Ejemplo

```
System.out.println(formateador.format(1265377));
```

> imprime 1,265,377

Comment: Oh, funciona... Le agradezco inmensamente su apoyo.

Comment: Me alegra mucho :)